# Perguntas sobre LINUX, módulos, extensões e etc

Tags: suporte

Hoje me surgiu a dúvida de como instalar o Memcached no meu servidor(LINUX), procurei pela internet e não existe um tutorial pelo menos recente que me de segurança o suficiente para eu tentar aplicar no servidor, e como conheço a STACK pensei em logo tirar a dúvida por aqui, mas não me sinto confortável..

Existe uma comunidade da stack pt para tratar destas dúvidas(mais referentes a esta plataforma)? E se não houver, poderei tirar aqui mesmo(visto que não é o foco desta comunidade, pelo menos acredito eu)? Ou seria melhor eu recorrer a comunidades da Stack que possuem este aval(ou seja, EN).

Enfim, procurar o que têm aval próprio lá fora, ou postar aqui mesmo?

Comment: Memcached em um servidor php? Acredito que esteja dentro do escopo, não custa perguntar e ver o que acontece.

Comment: Concordo com o @GuilhermeNascimento. Perguntas sobre como configurar o ambiente de produção (ou desenvolvimento, ou testes, etc) tem grande chance de serem bem recebidas.